# Which teams are the top teams in FIFA 12?

Tags: fifa-12

In short I want to find out which are the best teams in FIFA 12. I know this is quite an open ended question but it would be good to see some sort of comparison chart for team stats, anybody have a link for that or something similar?

Something like follows would be useful...

```
Team    Att    Mid    Def    Total
------------------------------------
A       90     90     90     270
B       89     88     87     264
C       90     89     82     261
```

I need to decide which team I want to be in an upcoming league I am going to be part of. I need to have a shortlist of my preferred teams, and will also be wanting to test them out before it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant provide a chart right now but these following teams are definitely in the top 3:

```
1. Barcelona 
2. Real Madrid
3. Manchester United
```

These teams are definitely in the top 10 as well:

```
1. Manchester City
2. Chelsea
3. AC Milan
4. Inter Milan
5. Bayern Munich
```

Hopefully, it gives you an idea of what team to pick.

Comment: I am liking AC and Bayern so will have to give them a test. Top 3 are nto to my liking. Chelsea I play with regularly so have a good sense of formation and style with them.

Comment: http://www.futhead.com/12/clubs/?sort=-golds

Answer (score -1):

The best teams in FIFA 12 are:

1. Real Madrid
2. Bayern Munich
3. Barcelona

Comment: Perhaps you could give an explanation as to why these particular teams are "best". A source or some kind of reference would make this answer much better.